# How can I use a C++ function template in R via Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I want to use the function template `to_string` to convert a `int` to `string`, in C++ there is no problem but if I do it in R it gives me the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'std::string to_string(T)':
main.cpp:38:11: error: 't' was not declared in this scope
 ss << t;
       ^
main.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* sourceCpp_1_to_string(SEXP)':
main.cpp:134:36: error: 'T' was not declared in this scope
 Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< T >::type tSEXP(tSEXPSEXP);
                                ^
 main.cpp:134:38: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< T >::type tSEXP(tSEXPSEXP);
                                  ^
 main.cpp:134:46: error: expected initializer before 'tSEXP'
 Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< T >::type tSEXP(tSEXPSEXP);
                                          ^
 main.cpp:135:44: error: 'tSEXP' was not declared in this scope
 rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(to_string(tSEXP));
                                        ^
  make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I am confused, is there an alternative?

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
template <typename T>
std::string to_string(T t)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

R fundamentally doesn’t know about templates. In fact, the interface between R and C++ is a *C [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)*, so all C restrictions apply.

So not only can’t you export a function template, you also can’t call a non-exported template meaningfully because the type you’re getting from R is a dynamic *runtime type*, not a static type. You’ll need to perform runtime type dispatch.

Answer (score 3):

I have nothing to add to Konrad's answer in terms of why your attempt failed; but from past experience I would recommend (*edit: see update below*) deferring to `Rcpp::as` for the conversion rather than `std::ostringstream`, as the former relies on the C-level `Rf_coerceVector` (IIRC), and therefore should produce results more consistent with R's `as.character` (e.g., floating point, `Date`, and `POSIXt` values). In either case, the [`RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR` macro](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/macros/dispatch.h#L102) is your friend, eliminating a bunch of boilerplate:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

template <int RTYPE>
CharacterVector as_character(const Vector<RTYPE>& x) {
    return as<CharacterVector>(x);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP to_string(SEXP t)
{
    RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR(as_character, t);
}

/*** R

to_string(1)
# [1] "1"

to_string(1.5)
# [1] "1.5"

to_string(1.5 + 2i)
# [1] "1.5+2i"

to_string(TRUE)
# [1] "TRUE"

to_string("abc")
# [1] "abc"

to_string(Sys.Date())
# [1] "2017-07-18"

to_string(Sys.time())
# [1] "2017-07-18 06:48:58"

*/
```

---

**Update**: As Dirk pointed out to me off-site, there is no need for the template function + `RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR` idiom in this particular case, as my template function `as_character` is simply calling the `CharacterVector` constructor. The following is equivalent, but much simpler:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector to_string(SEXP t) {
    return CharacterVector(t);
}
```